# how to find maximum and minimum values of a particular column using AWK

Tags: sorting, awk, sed

I am trying to find out the Minimum and Maximum values of 4th column in a large size file (4.3gb). I was able to find maximum value, but was not able to find minimum values. I tried many commands and i couldnt get exact results and could you please exaplin the difference in out put of 2 command and give solution for finding minimum values of the column.

```
sort -k4 -n 38690797_no_null.txt | head -1 | awk '{print $4}'
```

**output:** No output was seen just a blank

```
cut -f4 -d " " 38690797_no_null.txt| sort -n | head
```

**Output:**

0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000

i tried this command also

```
awk 'function max(x){i=0;for(val in x){if(i<=x[val]){i=x[val];}}return i;}
function min(x){i=max(x);for(val in x){if(i>x[val]){i=x[val];}}return i;}
{a[$4]=$4;next} END{minimum=min(a);maximum=max(a);print "Maximum = "maximum " and Minimum = "minimum}' junk.txt
```

**Output:** Maximum = 0.812698 and Minimum =

ALL THE ABOVE COMMAND WORK PERFECTLY FOR SMALL SIZE FILE (200 lines), BUT ITS NOT WORKING FOR LARGE SIZE FILE (38,690,794 lines)

Comment: Ditto. Solution of @EdMorton is cleanest and safest in there, imho.

Comment: @Cyrus i tried all the methods and checked the other post also.. its doesnt give proper minimum value.. could you explain the difference between 1st command and 2nd command

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus all the command i tested for small files, it's working perfectly, but it not in large size